# Adding configuration class to SpringBootTest breaks component scan

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-boot-test, component-scan, fongo

I am trying to disable real Mongo connection and replace it with Fongo mock in tests.

Here is my test class:

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class ControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @MockBean
        private MyService service;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void performTest() throws Exception {
            ... logic ...
        }
    }
```

It works fine unless I try to add my configuration file changing this line:

```java
    @SpringBootTest
```

to this:

```java
    @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
```

config class itself:

```java
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableMongoRepositories
    public class TestConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected String getDatabaseName() {
            return "FongoDB";
        }

        @Override
        public Mongo mongo() {
            return new Fongo(getDatabaseName()).getMongo();
        }
    }
```

Then application fails to find beans and throws the next exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 more
```

How can I fix it and apply additional configuration properly?

Comment: See https://github.com/arthurportas/arthurportas.wordpress.com/tree/master/nosql/mongo/fongo-hello-world

Answer (score 7):

try use

- @SpringBootTest
     @Import(value = TestConfig.class)

instead of 
 @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)

Comment: You will get this error if you do thisjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use ContextConfiguration or SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
 at

Answer (score 2):

keep @SpringBootTest and then create a class using @TestConfiguration with the beans in as follows:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TransactionManagerTestConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public String getDatabaseName() {
       return "FongoDB";
   }

   @Bean
   public Mongo mongo() {
       return new Fongo(getDatabaseName()).getMongo();
   }
}
```

As per the javadoc: Configuration that can be used to define additional beans or customizations for a test. Unlike regular Configuration classes the use of TestConfiguration **does not prevent auto-detection of SpringBootConfiguration**.