# Spring Boot @Autowire not working in @TestCofiguration inner class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2 application with an integration test like follows

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = ExchangeRateStoreApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class GenerateStrategyRatesTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        JdbcPersistenceHelper jdbcPersistenceHelper(@Autowired EntityManager entityManager) {
            return new JdbcPersistenceHelper(entityManager);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
```

However, the `@Autowired EntityManager` in `Config` class is not being resolved by spring and I don't know why.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've tried but I'm afraid it doesn't work either...

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53608522/4796021

Comment: Yeah! It works!! Thanks @DavidPérezCabrera! Do you mind to post your answer so I can mark it as solved?